# Comparar arrays en Swift

Tags: swift

Tengo dos arreglos: en arreglo 1 cambian los valores, el arreglo 2 tiene que sincronizarse con el primero, pero sin perder las posiciones del valor.
He probado con `difference(from:)` pero reordena los valores del arreglo 2.
Aquí como debería ser:

```swift
let array1 = ["01", "06", "17", "22", "33", "45", "04"]
var array2 = ["04", "17", "22", "10", "01", "34"]

//
...
// Resultado
var array2 = ["04", "17", "22", "01", "06", "33", "45"]
```

El orden de los valores que hay en arreglo 2 tienen que permanecer, borrar los que no haya en el arreglo 1 y agregar al final del arreglo 2 los que faltan del arreglo 1.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto sea ayuda, agregando un método filter al array2 y array1 y utilizando el metodo includes se puede lograr el resultado esperado

```js
let array1 = ["01", "06", "17", "22", "33", "45", "04"];
var array2 = ["04", "17", "22", "10", "01", "34"];

  array2 = array2.filter((item) => array1.includes(item));
  array1 = array1.filter((item) => !array2.includes(item));

  array2 = [...array2, ...array1];

  console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu idea, esto me ayuda a encontrar la solución.

Comment: @J.B  espero que esta edicion sea tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la mejor solución que consigo

```swift
let array1 = ["01", "06", "17", "22", "33", "45", "04"]
var array2 = ["04", "17", "22", "10", "01", "34"]

let remove = (array2.filter{!array1.contains($0)})
let append = (array1.filter{!array2.contains($0)})
for i in remove {
    array2 =  array2.filter {$0 != i}
}
array2.append(contentsOf: append)

print("array2:\(array2)")
// array2:["04", "17", "22", "01", "06", "33", "45"]
```

Comment: No olvides explicar cómo funciona tu código. Puede que para ti sea obvio, pero para otros quienes lleguen a tener un problema similar, no. Lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta. Por último, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.